# VScode Tailwind CSS Intellisense plugin only works when I add a space before class names

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, tailwind-css

I followed the [tailwind installation guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs) for nextjs

Below is my `tailwind.config.js` file

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

But the intellisense only works when I start my class names with a space.

[image]

Below is my vscode settings.json file. I thought something there might be causing the bug, but commenting out the entire file does nothing to solve the problem.

```
{
  "color-highlight.markerType": "dot-before",
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "autoprefixer.formatOnSave": true,
  "autoprefixer.browsers": [
    "last 4 versions",
    "ie >= 9",
    "> 5%"
  ],
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "scss.format.newlineBetweenRules": false,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.js": "prettier-eslint",
  "workbench.settings.openDefaultKeybindings": true,
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
  },
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
}
```

Comment: check the property of that particular Eslint in your vscode. There might be some by default has been selected so you have to do it manually.

Comment: I disabled Eslint to check for this but the problem persists.

Comment: Same problem here. What I do is `CTRL + Space` to "activate" intellisense and then, type

Comment: I'm on a mac so `CTRL + Space` seems to be `Command + Space` for me which just opens my Spotlight searchbar...why is tailwind so hard to use.

Comment: Have you tried adding a VSCode config setting for `editor.quickSuggestions` (https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense#editorquicksuggestions)?

Comment: You can refer to this doc https://tailwindcss.com/docs/editor-setup and needs to fix your vs code extension config setting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did face this issue a while ago ([tailwindcss-intellisense #495](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense/issues/495)). It is due to how VS Code handles string context. Up till now, it is still a hit-and-miss for me, but I can live with it. With that said, adding the following to your `.vscode/settings.json` should solve the problem.

```json
{
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "strings": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In VSCode settings search for: **quick suggestions**
and turn on strings suggestions
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrKIf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Work around of this would be

> ctrl + space bar

Answer (score 0):

press `ctrl + shift + p`, then search for setting.json
Inside add the following line at the end:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "strings": true
  }
```

Comment: Hi, please note, the accepted answer has this exact code